# Using LIKE in sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sp-executesql

SET @whereCond = @whereCond + ' AND name LIKE ''%'' + @name + ''%'''

Is there something wrong here? After I generate where condition, I execute it with `sp_executesql`, but I did get anything. When I SELECT the same thing without sp, it's ok.

How to use LIKE in sp_executesql? Can you bring some examples, please?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

```
declare @name nvarchar(50)

set @name = 'a'

SELECT *
    FROM Tbl_Persons WHERE 1 = 1  AND lastname LIKE '%a%' 

exec sp_executesql 
  N'SELECT *
    FROM Tbl_Persons WHERE 1 = 1  AND lastname LIKE ''%@name%''', 
  N'@name nvarchar(50)',
  @name=@name
```

First query returns values, second one doesn't return anything.

What's the difference?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following works for me

```
declare @name varchar(50)

set @name = 'WAITFOR'


exec sp_executesql 
  N'select * from sys.messages WHERE text  LIKE ''%'' + @name + ''%''', 
  N'@name varchar(50)',
  @name=@name
```

I think the problem must lie elsewhere.

**Edit:** Following your update you need to use

```
exec sp_executesql 
  N'SET @name = ''%'' + @name + ''%'';
    SELECT *
    FROM Tbl_Persons WHERE 1 = 1  AND lastname LIKE @name', 
  N'@name nvarchar(50)',
  @name=@name
```

As it stands you are searching for text containing the actual substring `@name`

Comment: I've checked your script and it's working, but mine doesn't work. I've edited my question. thank you.

Comment: why is this assignment '@name=@name' required here, Isn't just enough to pass @name ?

Comment: @IKriKan The first name is the parameter used in the query expression and the second name is the variable containing the value (that should substitute the parameter). I prefer to give them different names though.

Comment: This doesn't work when @name contains apostrophe character (single quotation mark) , for example D'souza

Comment: @PalakM - yes it does. This isn't creating the SQL string itself with concatenation

Comment: See for example `declare @name varchar(50)

set @name = 'it''s'


exec sp_executesql 
  N'select * from sys.messages WHERE text  LIKE ''%'' + @name + ''%''', 
  N'@name varchar(50)',
  @name=@name`  which returns these results https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8XRv.png

Comment: I was missing escape character. thank you